# Setting a sender name when sending an email with smtplib and python

Tags: python, django, smtp, smtplib

I am creating an endpoint where a user can get sent an email with a code to reset their password with.

When sending the email, I am using the built in smtplib that comes bundled with python.

When a request is made to the endpoint, I want the sender name to appear instead of the raw email.   How can I accomplish this?

Here's my code:

```
 code = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_letters + string.digits) for _ in range(8))
 content = 'Subject: {}\n\n{}'.format('Your code to reset your password:', 'Your Code: {}'.format(code))
 mail = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
 mail.ehlo()
 mail.starttls()
 mail.login(os.environ.get('email'), os.environ.get('password'))
 mail.sendmail(os.environ.get('email'), user.email, content)
 mail.close()
```

When searching the web for similar  questions, the only solution that came across was to add this line of code:  **content['From'] = "Your name "**

Adding this line of code didn't send the email at all.

Does anybody know how to add the sender name to the email? Thank You.

Comment: If you are actually using Django here... you might want to look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/email/ - don't forget that you're going to somewhere store that code to be able to check it's valid at some point later as well...